# Delete data from .Trash in hdfs

Tags: hive, hdfs

When I delete data from hdfs if goes to .Trash.

I can either use

```
hdfs dfs -rm -skipTrash /path_to_directory
```

or use

```
hdfs dfs -expunge
```

to remove data already in .Trash

Two questions:

1. While dropping table in Hive - do the tables go to .Trash or they are removed permanently?
2. Is this possible to remove data from .Trash for all users? Assuming I have required privileges...

Comment: For Hive-managed tables, DROP table will delete Hive metadata and move data to .Trash unless you specify PURGE as part of the DROP statement, https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableCreate/Drop/TruncateTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dropping an **external table**, nothing is going to happen as it doesn't delete any data.

For **managed tables**, yes all the data files will go to the .Trash directory of the user who ran the `drop` command. However it's only data and not the metadata.

For other part of your question, yes you could delete the **.Trash** directory of any user if you have required privilege.